# How to push values into array using radio buttons in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to push values to an array whenever i check the radio button.  How can I accomplish this?

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
     <div class="col-sm-12" >
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 nopadding" >
            <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Have you taken any admission tests? (eg. IELTS, GRE, etc)</label>
            <div class="btn-group col-xs-12 nopadding" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-click="checkMultiSelect(vm.studentObj,admission)" ng-class="{'active':vm.studentObj.test_taken === 'Y'}">
                  <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="vm.studentObj.test_taken" value="Y"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-click="checkMultiSelect(vm.studentObj,'test_taken','N')" ng-class="{'active':vm.studentObj.test_taken === 'N'}">
                  <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="vm.studentObj.test_taken" value="N"> No
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
     <div class="col-sm-12" >
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 nopadding" >
            <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Educational Info (High School/ Secondary/ Primary/ Pre School)</label>
            <div class="btn-group col-xs-12 nopadding" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-click="checkMultiSelect(vm.studentObj,Educational)" ng-class="{'active':vm.studentObj.test_taken === 'Y'}">
                  <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="vm.studentObj.test_taken" value="Y"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-click="checkMultiSelect(vm.studentObj,'test_taken','N')" ng-class="{'active':vm.studentObj.test_taken === 'N'}">
                  <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="vm.studentObj.test_taken" value="N"> No
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function

```
$rootScope.checkMultiSelect = function (data, key) {
  if (!data) {
    data = [];
  }
  var idx = data.indexOf(key);
  if (idx > -1) {
    data.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    data.push(key);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you put a POC in jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry i cant...........

Comment: Dont pass the array `vm.studentObj` in the function rather use `this.studentObj` in the controller's javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually push data to get an object representing the form. The data-binding in Angular does this for you.

```
<form ng-form="studentForm">
    <div class="form-group" show-errors>
         <div class="col-sm-12" >
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 nopadding" >
                <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Have you taken any admission tests? (eg. IELTS, GRE, etc)</label>
                <div class="btn-group col-xs-12 nopadding" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-class="{'active':studentObj.test_taken === 'Y'}">
                      <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="studentObj.test_taken" value="Y"> Yes
                    </label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-class="{'active':studentObj.test_taken === 'N'}">
                      <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="studentObj.test_taken" value="N"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" show-errors>
         <div class="col-sm-12" >
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 nopadding" >
                <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Educational Info (High School/ Secondary/ Primary/ Pre School)</label>
                <div class="btn-group col-xs-12 nopadding" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-class="{'active':studentObj.edu_info === 'Y'}">
                      <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="studentObj.edu_info" value="Y"> Yes
                    </label>
                    <label class="col-xs-6 btn btn-white" ng-class="{'active':studentObj.edu_info === 'N'}">
                      <input type="radio"  name="test_taken" ng-model="studentObj.edu_info" value="N"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Say someone fills out the form with the first radio as yes and the second as no. The output of `studentObj` will be

```
{
    test_taken: 'Y',
    edu_info: 'N'
}
```

This is the beauty of Angular. You don't need to manually push values, the data-binding does all of this for you and you don't need to clutter up your controller with unnecessary code.